# Error with a code: how to use dot operator for lists in C#, and relationship between lists, classes and properties

Tags: c#, xml, oop, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure out what types or operations are being used in my code (the code was originally taken from my supervisor, and modified to fit my scenario. It works, but I just need to clear a few things up and I know StackOverflow is a jackpot for clearing up any doubts :) ). The idea is to use C# to read an XML file with information on name/dimensions of four walls, compile all the info in a class (or a list... or both? I have some confusion here) and Instantiate these walls in Unity3d during runtime. The Unity parts I'm good with, but I need some help understanding what my C# stuff does.

One file, Wall.cs:

```
 public class Wall
 {
 public string Name { set; get; }
 public float Width { set; get; }
 public float Length { set; get; }
 }
```

Similarly, the XML file has parent tag "Walls", child tag "Wall" and subchild tags of "Name", "Width", "Length".

Main file ReadWalls.cs:

```
public class ReadWalls : MonoBehaviour {

public static List<Wall> ListofWalls = new List<Wall>();

public static List<Wall> ReadWallsXML(){
```

In this function there's a bunch of stuff to load the XML, using stuff like XmlNodeList, etc. I don't really care too much about this stuff but if anyone has any further info I wouldn't mind!

Then is a foreach loop that iterates through the XML such that it analyzes one Wall at a time. Inside it:

```
{Wall w = new Wall();
```

The next nested foreach analyzes one category (name or dimensions) at a time, at the subchild tag level in relation to the XML:

```
foreach (//code specifying subchild tag level)
{if (XmlNodeid.Name == "Name") {w.Name = XmlNodeid.InnerText;
//Similar if statements for "Width" and "Length", with w.Width and w.Length respectively.} //end of inner foreach

ListofWalls.Add(w);} //end of outer foreach

return ListofWalls;} //end of function

void Start() 
{WallsList = ReadWallsXML();
```

Here in the start function, I want to print all of the information into the console (name, length, width) using Debug.Log. The following works (just printing the name for simplicity):

```
foreach (Wall thiswall in WallsList)
{Debug.Log(thiswall.Name);}
```

If I try it this way, I get an error

```
foreach (Wall.Name thiswallsname in WallsList)
{Debug.Log(thiswallsname);}
}//end of class
```

Intellisense tells me "The type 'Name' does not exist in the type 'Wall''. So, what is Wall? My understanding was that we initiated it as a Class, with Properties of Name, Length, Width. To access properties, we use the dot operation (?). So why wouldn't Wall.Name access the Name property for each Wall object that was created? Also, why is the error saying Wall is a type? And one more thing, is Wall a list, class, or both? Intellisense says it's a Class (Line 2 of ReadWalls.cs) which makes sense. But where does the list aspect come into play? How are its properties related to the list?

Note that I took a significant amount of code out for (some) brevity, and also changed a few properties/names because my real code is quite lengthy. If you notice any logical or syntax errors, worry not, because the code works. The last part of this question is the most important: I just need help in analysing what the types of my variables/data are. I apologise if I've made any other mistakes, total noob here (to StackOverflow, C#, Unity and object oriented programming) if you couldn't tell already. Also thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Name` is a property of the `Wall` class, not a type of its own. The type of `Name` is `string`. Also, when you attempt `foreach(Wall.Name thiswallsname in WallsList)` you are, if it were a correct type, asking for each item in a list of that type. By that I mean that you are telling the code that you are expecting `WallsList` to be a collection of the type `Wall.Name` when it is actually a collection of `Wall` instances.

If you wanted to access the `Name` property of each `Wall` in the collection you would need to do the following:

```
foreach(Wall wall in WallsList)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}", wall.Name));
}
```

Which you show that you already have something basically identical to that.

`Wall` is a class, `WallsList` is a `List<Wall>` type. Basically a collection typed so that each item in the collection is strongly typed as a `Wall`. It is the same as the variable you have defined above `ListOfWalls`. As a note on `List<T>`: Any class can be made into a list of itself by defining a variable as a type of `List<ClassName>` - for instance `List<string>` will give you a list of `string` variables, `List<int>` will be a list of integers, `List<List<int>>` will be a list of integer lists... so on and so forth.

To print the values of each of the properties you would need to list each one out within the foreach loop:

```
foreach(Wall wall in WallsList)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Name: {0}", wall.Name));
   sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Width: {0}", wall.Width.ToString()));
   sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Length: {0}", wall.Length.ToString()));
   Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Of course, you could also look into reflection to dynamically retrieve a list of property names and values from the `Wall` class within the foreach loop, but using the above example will work just as well if you already know the property names.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense. It didn't occur to me that List<Wall> would be a list of solely Wall class instances. When reading beginner documentation on lists, I noticed a lot of List<int> or List<string> examples, now I see the connection between the explicit int/string type declaration and the implicit Wall type declaration.

Comment: Sure, I added some more. I was trying to hit each of your points and make it as clear as possible. Also, regarding the XML... instead of comparing string contents of the XML, it looks like it would be intended to be de/serialized to/from the `Wall` class. deserializing XML into a class will automatically verify the XML (otherwise it wouldn't deserialize at all) and give you an instance of `Wall` from the XML itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, why is the error saying Wall is a type? And one more thing, is
>   Wall a list, class, or both?

Wall is a class—the words "type" and "class" here are interchangeable. WallsList, as the name would imply, is a list made up of Wall objects.

> So why wouldn't Wall.Name access the Name property for each Wall
>   object that was created?

The `foreach` statement allows you a shorthand way to iterate through collections (specifically, anything that implements the `IEnumerable` interface). Most commonly, you'll use this with List or Array objects. But both Lists and Arrays are made up of a certain type of objects that is declared when they are created. In this example, your WallsList object is defined as `List<Wall>`: it's a collection of Wall objects. So when the `foreach` is iterating through, it only pulls out each Wall object as a whole, not the individual properties.

> To access properties, we use the dot operation (?). So why wouldn't
>   Wall.Name access the Name property for each Wall object that was
>   created?

In as simple terms as I can think of, you have to create an instance of a class before you can access the properties. Declaring `Wall blah = new Wall();` allocates a space in memory for that new object and then `blah.Name = "hello";` sets the property. Trying to call `Wall.Name = "hello";` directly results in an error because you're trying to set something that, from the computer's perspective, doesn't exist.

Comment: I see, clearly I need to brush up on my concepts. Thanks for your help!